# How can I get Angular to display the string of a variable using scope as a data model?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope, data-modeling

```
$scope.headers = {score: "test", gaps:"test2", strand:"test3"};
        if (line.lastIndexOf("Score", 0) === 0 ) {
            $scope.headers.score = line;       }
```

My view now displays "test" when I put {{headers.score}} in the HTML. Is there a way to get{{headers.score}} to display a string by attaching a variable to the scope?

Example:
( var a = "blanhkaldl"; therefore, {{headers.score}} dispalys "blanhkaldl" )

Answer (score 0):

...sorry; I sneezed, tabbed and hit space to prematurely post, all at the same time.

There are lots and lots of solutions, here.

You might want to get a little more specific about what you're actually trying to accomplish.
You don't have to give us everything, but the solution will depend, I guess, on what you expect to change, and where you're declaring the logic, and what else you have in your template.

Inside of your template, you can use ng-if, ng-show or ng-switch, to change elements, based on if you want element-structure to change:

```
$scope = {
    isOpen : false,
    article : { author : "", date : "", title : "", content : "" }
};


 <article >
     <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
     <span ng-if="!isOpen" ng-click="isOpen = true">...show</span>
     <p ng-if="isOpen">{{ article.content }}</p>
 </article>
```

Alternatively, you can use ternary in the interpolation:

```
<p>{{ isOpen ? article.content : '...show' }}</p><button ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen">toggle</button>
```

Angular will also update your view as your model changes.
As long as you're making your changes inside of Angular (after an Angular `$http` call, or inside of an Angular `$timeout`, or when a user triggers an `ng-click`, etc), you don't have to do anything else; Angular will check all of your scopes to see what has changed, and update your views.

If you **DO** make changes outside of Angular:

```
xhr.onload = ...  
button.onclick ...  
window.onresize ...  
setTimeout ...
```

then after your event is triggered, you should either call

`$scope.$apply(function ($scope) { /* make changes in here */ });`

or

`$timeout(function ($scope) { /* change here, and Angular will start an $apply if one isn't already running */ });`

***"$apply"*** being the phase where it actually runs through all of the changes it found, and updates all of the connected bits of your system.

The reason not to call `$scope.$apply` is that there's a chance that an `$apply` cycle is in the middle of running, already.
The sensible thing for Angular to do would probably just be to sneak your changes into that `$apply`, or schedule another $apply immediately after it's finished, to include your new changes...

...instead, it throws an error, telling you that "apply is already running".
Makes sense for debugging if you're building Angular, less sense when you just want to wire things together...
So use $timeout, instead.

But just having a `var` inside of your function scope itself isn't going to cut it.
It has to be something on your `$scope` or on your `controller` or in your template (if you mention values in your template that aren't on your scope, Angular puts them on your scope).

There's very little black magic driving Angular; most of it is just going through all of your $scopes, and checking every key/value on every scope in a loop (or sets of loops) [the "Digest" phase], and then updating all of the other scopes/views which were watching for those changes [the "Apply" phase], which might then kick off another round of changes, etc, until Angular can make it all the way through every $scope without any value, anywhere changing.

The $timeout() is there when you change something outside of that Digest/Apply cycle, and it's not an Angular-understood method (ng-*, $http, $q, etc), so Angular doesn't pick it up, and you want to give Angular a nudge to tell it something important happened.